# How to load font from file resource in Lotus Domino?

Tags: lotus-notes, lotus-domino, domino-designer-eclipse

I encounter the problem while page loading some web font file stored in the file resource using the url like "revicons.ttf?5510888":

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 400 (Bad Request).
```

I think it's because of "?5510888" cannot be recognized as correct Domino url command. Is there any workaround except storing the web font file under physical path "data\domino\html"?

Answer (score 2):

You need to add the ?open suffix in order for Domino to be able to serve the request:

```
revicons.ttf?open&v=5510888
```

Comment: Excellent! Please accept the answer as correct. Thanks :-)